# How to generate random numbers for Beta distribution in a range?

Tags: random, distributions

[In Excel](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/BETA-INV-function-e84cb8aa-8df0-4cf6-9892-83a341d252eb?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) I can just write:

```
BETA.INV(RAND(),alpha,beta,lowerbound,upperbound)
```

To generate a beta distributed random between **lower bound** and **upper bound**

How can I do the same in Mathematica?

In other words hat is the right way to scale the output of:

```
RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[3,3]]
```

So that instead of generating a number between 0 and 1 it gives me a number between 25 and 73?

In Excel I would just write:

```
BETA.INV(RAND(),3,3,25,73)
```

But I don't know what to do in Mathematica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just rescale it

```
RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[3,3]] * (max - min) + min
RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[3,3]] * 48 + 25
```

A plot:

```
Show[
 Histogram[Array[RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[3, 3]]*48 + 25 &, 100000], 48,"PDF"],
 Plot[{((1-((x-25)/48))^(-1+3)((x-25)/48)^(-1+3))/(48 Beta[3,3])}, {x, 25,73}]]
```

[image: histogram and PDF]

Answer (score 2):

Just to illustrate:

- `TransformedDistribution`
- `Rescale`

  ```
  td[a_, b_, min_, max_, n_] :=
  RandomVariate[
  TransformedDistribution[(max -min) x + min,
  x \[Distributed] BetaDistribution[a, b]], n]


  rs[a_, b_, min_, max_, n_] := 
  Rescale[RandomVariate[BetaDistribution[a, b], n], {0, 1}, {min, max}]
  ```

[image]